# UserControl slowing down Aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, code-behind, webusercontrol

I have a usercontrol which contains a GridView. When I use this usercontrol in aspx page it works fine. But when I select a row in the GridView, It works very slow.

Do you have any solution for getting it faster?

**1.UserControl**

**1.1.Html**
Parent Grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvChannelUC" name="gvChannelUCName" />
```

ChildGrid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContentServerUC"
```

**1.2.CodeBehind:**

PageLoad() function

```
    {
//Fill data for ParentGrid
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr = null;
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fullIndex", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IPAddress", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubNetMask", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Port", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MaxConnect", typeof(string)));
                if (valuesUC.interfaces!=null)
                foreach (IPSInterface IPSInteface in valuesUC.interfaces)
                {
                    foreach (IPSChannel ipsChannel in IPSInteface.channels)
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["fullIndex"] = ipsChannel.fullIndex;
                        dr["IPAddress"] = IPSInteface.LocalInterfaceIP;
                        dr["SubNetMask"] = IPSInteface.LocalInterfaceNetmask;
                        dr["Port"] = ipsChannel.localInterfacePort;
                        dr["MaxConnect"] = ipsChannel.maxConnections;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                Session["dt"] = dt;
                gvChannelUC.DataSource = dt;
                gvChannelUC.DataBind();
            }
    }
```

//Fill data for ChildGrid

```
protected void gvChannelSelected()
        {
            ip = IP;
            port = Port;
            if(  (((SetupIPServicesValues)Session["values"]).interfaces)!=null)
            foreach (IPSInterface IPSInteface in ((SetupIPServicesValues)Session["values"]).interfaces)
            {
                foreach (IPSChannel ipsChannel in IPSInteface.channels)
                {
                    string fullIndexFor = null;
                    string fullIndex = null;
                    fullIndex = gvChannelUC.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString().Trim();//=======1 mean fullIndex
                    fullIndexFor = ipsChannel.fullIndex.Trim();
                    if (fullIndex.Equals(fullIndexFor))//Compare Channel fullIndex with array
                    {
                        DataTable dtCS = null;
                        DataRow drCS = null;
                        dtCS = new DataTable();
                        dtCS.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fullIndex", typeof(string)));
                        dtCS.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IPAddress", typeof(string)));
                        dtCS.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Port", typeof(string)));
                        dtCS.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Notes", typeof(string)));
                        foreach (IPSServer ipServer in ipsChannel.servers)//Get Content Server from array to fill grid
                        {
                            drCS = dtCS.NewRow();
                            drCS["fullIndex"] = ipServer.fullIndex;
                            drCS["IPAddress"] = ipServer.address;
                            drCS["Port"] = ipServer.port;
                            drCS["Notes"] = ipServer.notes;
                            dtCS.Rows.Add(drCS);
                        }
                        Session["dtContentServer"] = dtCS;
                        gvContentServerUC.DataSource = dtCS;
                        gvContentServerUC.DataBind();

                        //Other controls                 
                        if (txtServerMonitoring.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtServerMonitoring, ipsChannel.IPSMonitoringPolicyListString);
                        if (txtServerMonitoring.Items.Count != 0)
                        {
                            string valueMonitorAPI = ipsChannel.monitoringPolicy.Trim();
                            if (valueMonitorAPI == "None")
                                txtServerMonitoring.Text = "None";
                            else if (valueMonitorAPI == "Echo")
                                txtServerMonitoring.Text = "Echo";
                            else if (valueMonitorAPI == "Connect")
                                txtServerMonitoring.Text = "Connect";
                            else if (valueMonitorAPI == "0")
                                txtServerMonitoring.Text = "0";
                        }

                        if (txtLoadBalancingPolicy.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtLoadBalancingPolicy, ipsChannel.IPSLoadBalancePolicyListString);
                        if (txtLoadBalancingPolicy.Items.Count != 0)
                            setLoadBalancePolicyFtp(ipsChannel.loadBalancePolicy);

                        if (txtConnectivity.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtConnectivity, ipsChannel.ConnectivityListString);

                        if (txtConnectivity.Items.Count != 0)
                        {
                            string valueAPI = ipsChannel.Connectivity.Trim();
                            if (valueAPI == "managed")
                                txtConnectivity.Text = "managed";
                            else if (valueAPI == "dsr")
                                //txtConnectivity.Text = "Direct Server Return";
                                txtConnectivity.Text = "dsr";
                            else if (valueAPI == "transparency")
                                txtConnectivity.Text = "transparency";
                            else if (valueAPI == "gateway")
                                txtConnectivity.Text = "gateway";
                        }

                        if (txtCachingStrategy.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtCachingStrategy, ipsChannel.IPSCachePortListString);
                        if (txtCachingStrategy.Items.Count != 0)
                            txtCachingStrategy.SelectedIndex = ipsChannel.cachePort;

                        if (txtSSL.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtSSL, ipsChannel.IPSSSLCertificateListString);
                        if (txtSSL.Items.Count != 0)
                            setCertificateName(ipsChannel.certificateName);

                        if (txtContentSSL.Items.Count == 0)
                            setDrdSource(txtContentSSL, ipsChannel.IPSSSLClientCertificateListString);
                        if (txtContentSSL.Items.Count != 0)
                            setClientCertificateName(ipsChannel.ClientCertificateName);
                        //=============6 drd end
                        chkEnableConnectionPolling.Checked = ipsChannel.CSGPoolEnabled;
                        if (ipsChannel.CSGPoolSize != null)
                            txtConnectionPoolSize.Text = ipsChannel.CSGPoolSize;

                        if (txtAvailableFP.Items.Count == 0)
                            if (ipsChannel.FlightPathSelectionListString != null)
                                setDrdSource(txtAvailableFP, ipsChannel.FlightPathSelectionListString);
                        lbl.Text = ipsChannel.SelectedFPRule;
                        return;//return void after fill data to Content Server
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**2.Aspx Main page**

2.1.Html:Place Holder for add dynamic UserControl

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDevices" runat="server" >
                                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

CodeBehind:

PageLoad() function:

```
//Add more dynamic UserControl to PlaceHolder
    foreach (DataRow row in dtDevicesListByRole.Rows)
                {
                wuc[i] = (Test2.SetupGroup.Ipservice.IpInterfaceUC)LoadControl("IpInterfaceUC.ascx");
    }
```

If you need detail,I'll add more.Thanks

Comment: Post some code or an example, the problem is far too vague right now.

Comment: I don't think it's a UserControl issue, maybe showing your code could help us find out.

Comment: my guess would be your gridview does contain too much elements and produce huge viewstate so selecting an elemnt cause all that viewstate to post and that makes your page slow.

Comment: @Middas ,@Mahdi I have add some code on description.Thanks

Comment: @adt probably has the correct suggestion, how many records are you loading onto the page at once?  If it's a ton, consider using a Pager.

Comment: If I register a UserControl(which contain GridView).It seem faster than register 2 UserControl

Comment: I guess that It redesign 2 UserControl when I press SelectIndex at Gridview of a UserControl.I use debug of VisualStudio and recognized it.